# how to initialize a method parameter with null

Tags: iphone, ios, methods

I have a custom method that accepts two parameters. I am using this method with several different data sets, of which some only need to have one array passed and other two.. I am wondering if its possible to pass one null if needed?

//method

```
- (IBAction)startSortingTheArray:(NSArray *)arrayData:(NSArray *)arrayDataB
{
//..
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to pass one null if needed, as long as your implementation is coded to expect it that way. For example:

```
- (void)startSortingTheArray:(NSArray *)arrayData arrayB:(NSArray *)arrayDataB
{
    if (arrayData != nil) {
        // process arrayData
    }
    if (arrayDataB != nil) {
        // process arrayDataB
    }
}
```

To make your interface more clean, you could also provide an alternate signature of the method and do something like:

```
- (void)startSortingTheArray:(NSArray *)arrayData
{
    [self startSortingTheArray:arrayData arrayB:nil];
}
```

Note that I changed the return type from what you initially posted. You had it declared as an IBAction which should take sender as its argument, not an array as you were passing it. I assume you meant for this to be applied to another function and not really to an interface builder action.

Comment: okay great. thanks for that I started to code it all up and wasnt getting error but just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something hidden.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you could do that. Then in your `startSortingTheArray` handle such cases... (i.e. code such a way that you dont assume both `arrayData` & `arrayDataB` are present).

Another suggestion I would like to make is if the parameters are getting too many & you have this scenario of some params being present & some not. Then use 1 object as parameter. This object is encapsulated & all the data points are properties of this object. That way your code is much clear & cleaner, easy to maintain blah, blah...

Answer (score 0):

if you are using this method in interface builder e.g attaching it to UIButton then its not possible.

but in if your are calling this method in other methods then yes

```
[self startSortingTheArray:nil arrayB:nil];

- (IBAction)startSortingTheArray:(NSArray *)arrayData:(NSArray *)arrayDataB
{
if(arrayData == nil){
// do something
}
if(arrayDataB == nil){
// do something
}
if(arryaData == nil && arrayData == nil){
// do something
}
```

//..
}